# I continually get an error when trying to "make" suckless terminal

Tags: compiling, make

I am currently attempting to install Suckless-terminal. I have installed this application once prior with zero hitches, so this threw me off  this time. I ran:

```
git clone https://git.suckless.org/st
cd st
sudo make clean install
```

The error message that I am getting is:

```
cp config.def.h config.h
c99 -I/usr/X11R6/include  `pkg-config --cflags fontconfig`  `pkg-config --cflags freetype2` -DVERSION=\"0.8.4\" -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=600  -O -c st.c
Package fontconfig was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `fontconfig.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'fontconfig' found
Package freetype2 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `freetype2.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'freetype2' found
/bin/sh: 1: c99: not found
make: *** [Makefile:22: st.o] Error 127
```

The README says that the "xlib headers" are necessary to install but I was unable to find this package. I presumed it was part of "xorg" which I already had installed. I tired to understand exactly what it was saying I was missing was but I had a hard time understanding it. I've tried for quite a long while and I am all out of ideas. Any thoughts or help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to install necessary development packages for [*fontconfig.pc*](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=fontconfig.pc), [*freetype2.pc*](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=freetype2.pc) and X11:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libfontconfig1-dev libfreetype-dev x11proto-dev libx11-dev libxft-dev
```

And then retry compilation.